# ERROR:root:Line magic function `%azureml` not found?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a "Blank Jupyter Notebook" project in Azure ML Workbench. When I try to run the Sample notebook found in the project, I get this error message:

```
ERROR:root:Line magic function `%azureml` not found.
```

What is missing?

Comment: looks like a bad notebook, which sample are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your kernel. I mean, do not use "`local`" kernel, use "`project_name local`" or any kernel which depends on your project .config file. You can change it on `Jupyter` from Kernel section on the top of the menu.

Comment: I already changed the Kernel to use the Azure ML Docker container. The container was prepped successful, but I get this error.

Comment: Can you do it again on a local(without using Docker)?